Simple regex, but polynomial regular expression error from CodeQL
I have a really simple regex (/<[^>]*?>/g) which strips tags and leave text. I know it isn't perfect, and I know that I should be used a DOM parser for such a test, but please humour me :-)
CodeQL gives me a warning about this expression:

Polynomial regular expression used on uncontrolled data
Some regular expressions take a long time to match certain input strings to the point where the time it takes to match a string of length n is proportional to nk or even 2n. Such regular expressions can negatively affect performance, or even allow a malicious user to perform a Denial of Service ("DoS") attack by crafting an expensive input string for the regular expression to match.

I cannot for the life of me see how that regex can have performance issues. I've experimented on regex101 with it and I've been reading about catastrophic backtracking, but it but I'm just not seeing it here.
Can anyone explain to me why that regex would be flagged? Or might this be a false positive situation?

Do not use lazy quantifier here, it makes little sense as it slows down matching. Use the regular <[^>]*> pattern.

@WiktorStribiżew Thank you! I'd been looking at it so long - obvious in hindsight!

Actually, that didn't resolve the issue at hand with the polynomial error from CodeQL. I'm at a loss.

Because there is no error with the patterns, the error is with CodeQL. It is too stupid to judge regexps. Disable it.

For what it's worth, https://makenowjust-labs.github.io/recheck/playground/ also says the regex is vulnerable, when < is repeated extremely often. Though maybe the performance impact is not that great compared to other vulnerable patterns, and I am not completely sure how to improve the pattern. Maybe use [^<>] instead of just [^>]?
